# Using variable values within different scenarios in a feature, capybara

Tags: variables, capybara

I have a feature with 4 scenarios. I would like to use the value of 1 variable I set in scenario 1 across different steps and in Scenario 2.

I use $ but this is not set. I am assuming $ value remains the same across a feature

```
When(/^the user goes to manageusers, picks one of the secondary users$/) do
  click_link "Admin"
  click_link "Manage Users"
  emailofuser=ENV["email"].to_s
  atpos = emailofuser.index('@')
  emailofuser = emailofuser[0,atpos]
  page.body.to_s.scan(/<td>(.*?)@ABC.com<\/td>/).flatten().each do |w|
    if "#{w}" != emailofuser
    $secondaryUserEmail = "#{w}" + "@ABC.com"
    break
    end
  end
end

When(/^the secondary user logs in with password "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
  if  getURL != URI.parse(current_url)
    visit getURL
  end
  find(:xpath,"//input[@id='user_email']").set($secondaryUserEmail )
  fill_in "user_password", :with => arg
  click_button "Sign in"
end
```

In the Above Step, the steps are in 1 scenario in a feature file and I also have the same step secondary user in Scenario 2 within a feature. the variable $secondaryuserEmail some times does not get set and login as a secondary user fails.

Whats the best way for me to declare variables that I can access across steps within a scenario and across scenarios within a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out why $secondaryuserEmail does not get set.  That sounds like a bug somewhere in the app you're testing.  If it's not a bug, you should try to handle the exception.

To your original question, it might be a good idea to set variables in helper methods, then call these methods to access them using instance variables.  Most people generally recommend against sharing variables across scenarios but I've used helper methods in order to store variables throughout my specs that normally go unchanged.